# Vanishing of the Wronskian of a 2nd order ODE in the nonhomogeneous case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An old exam question made me question what I believed was true about the Wronskian. It goes as follows: Let $\phi_1,\phi_2$ be two solutions of a linear, second order ODE on the interval $(0,1).$ Show that $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are linearly independent iff the Wronskian $W(f_1,f_2)(t) \neq 0$ *for all* $t \in (0,1).$

I am confused in part because different sources approach the question differently. For Arnold it is completely obvious, at least in the homogeneous case. I think his reasoning is as follows: by the existence and uniqueness theorem, for any time $t \in (0,1),$ map $\phi \mapsto (\phi(t),\dot{\phi}(t),\ldots,\phi^{(n-1)}(t))$ gives us a linear isomorphism between the space of solutions of a linear, homogeneous equation of order $n$ and the phase space $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Thus a system $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ of solutions is fundamental iff their Wronskian doesn't vanish for some $t$ iff their Wronskian never vanishes. Is this line of reasoning correct? (Note that it only applies to the homogeneous case.)

Other authors, still in the homogeneous case, appeal to Abel's identity to show that the Wronskian vanishes somehwere iff it vanishes everywhere.

But what about the nonhomogeneous case? Abel's identity doesn't apply in this settings, right? Is this why we absolutely need to work with a second order ODE? What would be the correct way to think about this?

I guess my question could be summarized as:

> In this problem, is it implicit that we are only interested in the homogeneous case because it is the most natural setting in which to talk about linear dependence of solutions (because in the nonhomogeneous case the solutions don't even form a vector space)?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? It seems that you have few sub-questions here, maybe it's better to rephrase them explicitly?

Comment: @Evgeny Sorry, I realize that the question is almost as confused as I am! I tried to summarize my concerns a bit.

Comment: 1) For nonhomogeneous case solutions don't form the vector space, but they form the linear manifold. If you have $n+1$ solutions for $n$th order linear equation you can ask whether they are affine independent or not. It's a consequence of fact that general solution of nonhomogeneous equation is a sum of any particular solution and general solution of homogeneous equation. So, it's quite unnatural (IMHO) to speak about linear (in)dependence here. 2) In higher order equations (and systems) you can use Ostrogradskii-Liouville formula which describes the differential equation for Wronskian.